# Group by and count values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

Im new to Django.

I have different classes (Stock, Portfolio, Trades)

What Im trying to achieve is a summery of all trades per stock.

So Basicly this is how my rows are now

[image]

I want to combine or group by `stock_id` and do a sum of `open_price` and `quantity`.

[image]

I tried with

```
Trade.objects.filter(portfolio=1).values('stock__name').aggregate(stock_total=Count('stock',distinct=True))
```

But that doesnt work.

How do I need to write the query to get that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Trade.objects.filter(portfolio=1).values('stock__name').annotate(stock_total=Count('entry'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I calculate values as well directly in here? Example, return a collumn, where I do quantity*open_price for each row and then sum it for each stock

Comment: Yes, I think you can do that just give a try and let me know.

Comment: `.annotate(total_quantity=Sum('quantity'),total_buy_price=Sum("quantity*open_price"))` somthing like that? Or is there another way, since it doesnt work

Comment: @Sharpless512, No you can't do this way.

Comment: How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

What about this,

```
from django.db.models import Count

Trade.objects.filter(portfolio=1).values('stock__name').annotate(stock_total=Count('entry')).order_by('stock__name')
```